# ElasticSearch Tagline: How to Change

Tags: elasticsearch

How in the world to you change the ridiculous and useless tagline in ElasticSearch?

'tagline' is not found in /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml, and when I add it, it has no effect.

Is it hard-wired into the code? What is the point of the dang thing if it can't be changed?

The intertubes seem totally silent on this.... just a thousand results repeating the same ridiculous and useless tagline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same way you cannot change the tagline of any company (intellectual property anyone?), that tagline cannot be changed as well and is hardcoded into [`RestMainAction.java`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/c50b22f95f48119213156bdb634925e1be91b794/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/rest/action/main/RestMainAction.java#L90).

It should be merely considered as Elasticsearch's way of saying "Hello world".

Comment: Well then thank you that is a critical point to understand. A textbook example of the poorly understood boundary between the proprietary and open source portions of a product.  Wherein, within a single JSON API response there are portions that are open source and others that are corporately hard-wired. WOW. much further thought is required given this information.